# Unexpected token in JSX when using conditional statements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to wrap every 3 items with a carousel component, but unfortunately as soon as I change the `<p>start</p> <p>end</p>` test element to the real component I get the following error:

```
"Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?",
```

```js
const Alerts = (props) => {
  const alerts = props.data;
  let pager = 1;
  return (
    <ul className={styles.alerts}>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={30}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        {alerts.map((e, index) => (
          <>
            {pager % 4 === 0 || pager === 1 ? (<p>start</p>) : ""}
            <div key={index} id={`alert-${index}`} className={styles.alert}>
              <div className={styles.alert__content}>
                <div className={styles.alert__content_top}>
                  <strong>
                    {e.token}
                    <a href={e.token_link}>
                      <i className="fa fa-external-link"></i>
                    </a>
                  </strong>
                  <span>{e.date}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.alert__desc}>{e.description}</div>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.alert__type}>{e.type}</div>
            </div>
            {pager % 3 === 0 ? (<p>end</p>) : ""}
            {pager === 3 ? (pager = 0) : ""}
            {(pager = pager + 1)}
          </>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

After the modification the lines looks like this:

```
{pager % 4 === 0 || pager === 1 ? (<SwiperSlide>) : ""}
```

and

```
{pager % 4 === 0 || pager === 1 ? (</SwiperSlide>) : ""}
```

What's wrong with the syntax? The numbers from the pager variable also visible on the site, maybe it's related to my syntax error?

Comment: You can't do assignments like `{(pager = pager + 1)}` hanging in the JSX

Comment: You need to update pager as a state instead of assignment. For updating the state , you can use useState hooks or this.setState.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `<p>start</p>` is correct JSX element. And `<SwiperSlide>` is just a part of element.

I'd recommend you convert your initial data array into a new array with small arrays with 3 elements in each. And go through it with two maps:

```
function splitToBulks(arr, bulkSize = 20) {
    const bulks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(arr.length / bulkSize); i++) {
        bulks.push(arr.slice(i * bulkSize, (i + 1) * bulkSize));
    }
    return bulks;
}

const Alerts = (props) => {
  const alerts = splitToBulks(props.data, 3);
  let pager = 1;
  return (
    <ul className={styles.alerts}>
      <Swiper
        spaceBetween={30}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        {alerts.map((allerts3, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide>
           {allerts3.map((e, index) => (
            <div key={index} id={`alert-${index}`} className={styles.alert}>
              <div className={styles.alert__content}>
                <div className={styles.alert__content_top}>
                  <strong>
                    {e.token}
                    <a href={e.token_link}>
                      <i className="fa fa-external-link"></i>
                    </a>
                  </strong>
                  <span>{e.date}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.alert__desc}>{e.description}</div>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.alert__type}>{e.type}</div>
            </div>
            )}
    </SwiperSlide>
    )}
          </>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </ul>
  );
};
```